# Possible exploit: It's possible to get around the character limit in chat

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, chat, character-limit

You can send messages beyond the character limit in chat.

For example:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Nothing bad, just a smiley face.

In chat, this is what you get:

[image: chat-image]

However, you can send a POST request straight to the chat servers.

Instead of putting a client side restriction, could the check be done on the server side as well?
For example, we still get "Message is too long", but in the server side there's still a check.

[image: some-image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, we already do validate the length server side, using very similar logic to client side. There  is,  however, one specific special case that you are hitting here where longer single-line messages are sometimes permitted. I'm not overly concerned about abusing this as an exploit, but I'll tidy  it up a little to avoid some of the more obvious problem scenarios.